# Return random json object by length of category

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a `json` array with words in different languages that I want to alert randomly. The thing is that I have different number of words in every language, so when I use the code below, I am getting `undefined` at some cases (because some words has more languages than others, and so the length property is longer than it should be).

I have tried to use `all.french.length` at the end of line 2, but got an **error**. Does anybody know what should I do?

Thanks!

```js
all = [{"english":"cat", "french":"chat"}, {"english":"dog"}]
let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length);
alert('random: ' + all[z].french);
```

Edit:  I want it only to alert words only in the language I defined in line 3. In this case, I want only to display french words: only alert "chat" again and again. My original data of words is larger than that, of course, and has more languages, so I can't use 0.

Comment: what do you expect?, doing a ramdom only with elements with have french attribute ?

Comment: When there is no word in the language, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi, @DarrenSweeney and I want it only to alert words in the language I defined in line 3. In this case, I want only to display french words: only alert "chat". My original data of words is larger than that, of course, and has more languages, so I can't use 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a random element where the translation french exists you can filter your array

```js
const filteredArray = all.filter(element => 
    element.french === "" || element.french);

let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredArray.length);

alert('random: ' + filteredArray[z].french);
```

Comment: You're right, I wrote the code a little too fast, I change "all" to "filteredArray"

Comment: your code have an other problem, when french attribute has an empty string...

Comment: If I use Boolean(element.french), empty strings will be evaluate to false

Comment: yes, and that's why I suppose empty elements should be eliminated too, what is the interest to alert with an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that:

```js
const  all = [{"english":"cat", "french":"chat"}, {"english":"dog"}]

function myAlert(lang)
  {
  let arr = all.filter( e=>!!e[lang])
    , z   = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    ;
  alert('random: ' + arr[z][lang] )
  }

myAlert('french')

myAlert('english')
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I thought there has to be a another way to access only the french objects with a different syntax, but this works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @matancl, you do a bad choice,  **Pierre-Louis** code is wrong and work only because the `cat` that is at array  zero...